# make a local variable to become a global variable

Tags: python

My question will be used in two .py:
main.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from tag_pivot import *
from mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
import sys

a = 'tag_'
b = 'pivot_'
c = 'STP_'
d = '_'
e = 'MTD_Level'
f = '()'
g = a+b+c+d+e+f
print(g)



class MainApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):


    def slot_method(self):
        combo = self.comboBox.currentText()//combo is local variable as it is from self the GUI
        combo2 = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
        eval(a + b + combo + d + combo2 + f)
      

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.init_connections()


    def init_connections(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.slot_method)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainApp()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

mainWindow.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainWindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.1
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 160, 111, 51))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 152, 151, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(88, 281, 151, 71))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "STP_"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "MM_"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Intra_Level"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "MTD_Level"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "YTD_Level"))

if __name__ == "__main__":


    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

my question is can I make the combo (come from self.comboBox.currentText()) from local variable to global variable as I want to assign the combo which is a string to another functions outside the class MainAPP. I am not sure how to make it happen, I assume others may have the same problem, so I post it here.
if I try to use ex.combo in main():

```
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainApp()
    gg = ex.combo
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the sys told me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Michael Su/Desktop/Michael_python/Tag_pivot/main.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Michael Su/Desktop/Michael_python/Tag_pivot/main.py", line 80, in main
    gg = ex.combo
AttributeError: 'MainApp' object has no attribute 'combo'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure why the tag_pivot part of the functions is necessary, if all you are trying to do is print specific values, why not print them directly from main instead of the long eval statement and different functions?

```
print(f"{c}{e}")  # prints STP_MTD
```

Or if you prefer a function, specifically for printing:

```
def printer_function(*args):
    print("".join(args))
```

This function can then be called from main and given any variables you want printed together. e.g.

```
printer_function(c, e)  # prints STP_MTD
```

I hope this helps, but if printing is not the only function you had in mind, let me know.

Comment: its not about the printing function, its about how to make self.comboBox.currentText() the local variable can only be used in class MainApp() to make it as a global variable

Comment: So you want to make the comboBox.currentText() text accessible elsewhere? If so it can be used in main() by accessing ex.combo or ex.combo2. Apologies if I haven't understood correctly.

Comment: seems cannot make MainAPP.comboBox.currentText() as a global variable...

Comment: Not a global variable, no, but you can call it wherever you need to by calling ex.comboBox.currentText() as ex is your object of the class MainApp, which you instantiated inside the function main()